# How to pick a selector inside a class for NSNotification?

Tags: ios, ios7, nsnotificationcenter

```
keyboard = [[FTKeyboardHelper alloc] init];
```

I have a keyboard helper class, and would like to call the method `keyboardShow` that is defined inside the `keyboard`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboard.keyboardShow:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                   object:nil];
```

However I get the error message `Excepted :`
Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:keyboard
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

I'm not sure you can "." Separate the selector, it's not a key path.

---

But I think that would be bad design, you should probably put that code inside your helper.
In the `- init` and unregister in the `- dealloc` or use a pair of `- register` and `- unregister`method to control this outside of the normal life cycle of your object.
But don't forget to unregister before the helper is deallocated, if not, you will crash the next time the keyboard shows up.

Comment: +1 on putting the observer inside of the keyboard helper class. I think that would be a better idea.